# How to fix 'Blocked by Play Protect / This app may be harmful'

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore

I've released an app on Play-store and another market but in 2 recent releases just users of that market have faced to this Warning: 
"Blocked by play protect / This app may be harmful / Install anyway"
How can I get rid of this?
I've even set V1 and v2 Checkboxes during making the release and I'm doing exactly what I've done for previous versions.(Same Key store, Alias and Password)
Is there any relationship between this problem and accessing to keyStore info by third-party? 
If yes, How?
If no, what is the solution other than submitting "Play Protect Appeal Form" every time after each update and missing a large number of users and customers?!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are they downloading apps play store or external

Comment: @ORBIT thanks for your consideration. No, there is no problem with play store. This occur when they update app from another markets.

Comment: Yup thats y ask

Comment: So sorry. You're right. I've edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First you need to understand how play protect works in google play.

Refer this site for more information https://www.google.com/about/unwanted-software-policy.html

- Remove all unnecessary external library before building release application.
- Check for any third party URL you are trying to invoke in application.
- Remove unnecessary permission.
- Use same keys you used for previous version.
- Your application should have proper security guideline setup like tokens.
- You should remove any code that block hardware
- You should not interact with system using shell commands.

In the end just https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2992033

Comment: Thanks @Kaushik, but this app has none of these problems and I've done your last advice, but it's not an appropriate way that every time I send this form and wait several days to solve this issue. This results in loss of the customers :(

Comment: can you send the link of your application in play store?

Comment: Play-Store:       https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.khedmatazma.customer&hl=en_US

Comment: i did not found any difficulty installing your application. It installed successfully.

Comment: Since Application distribution platform like play store keep track of installed application it is recommended to update the application from same platform.